# File not found error in pandas using csv files

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Jupyter and Data Science in general. So I was recently introduced with Pandas library in python and also the topic of file read/write. I wrote a code wherein I had to open my csv file on the notebook but I wasn't able to do so.

I have tried all methods that I could think of but none of them are working. Here are the codes that I tried to open my file

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    walmart_data = pd.read_csv("Walmart_Store_sales.csv")
```

**The other method that I tried was using the path (relative as well as absolute)**

```
walmart_data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project\walmart.csv")
```

**Also I used the encoding format,**

```
walmart_data = pd.read_csv(
    r"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project\walmart.csv",
    encoding="UTF-8"
)
```

Still after trying these methods, I was getting the same error again and again that my file was not found.

Comment: Did you try front slashes in your path instead of backslashes

Comment: Which folder are you in with your notebook? Try to copy the file that you want to open in this folder and try again to read it.

Comment: yes I did try the front slash as well, it didn't work out either.

Comment: The Backslash is also an escape charackter try to use double backslash on windows system or work with pathlib.Path

Comment: The double backslash also didn't work out either.

Comment: Thanks @LukasNeugebauer, that worked out perfectly.

Comment: are you sure the path is correct? `99.9%` its user error and the `.1` is some obscure error that is rarely, if ever reproducable.

Comment: Glad it worked. I don't really understand how that is, but I think jupyter notebooks can only access files that are in subfolders of the one from which you started the notebook. Also in the directory tree you will notice, that you can't go further up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In all of probability you do not have the .csv file placed where you think it is.
How about you try to access the file first at the path you are passing directly, say, from the run window?

1. hit `Win+R`
2. paste `"C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project\walmart.csv"` (with inverted commas, it'll take care if your username, xxxx,  has spacees)
3. hit enter.

If you can open it, there's no reason you shouldn't be able to open it in pandas for reading.

If you can't open it, go to the location (`C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project\`) and see if there actually is a file there called `walmart.csv`.

Also make sure that there is no special symbol/character in the filename/filepath that you have interpreted as something else. (eg. wælmært.csv instead of walmart.csv)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Way-01: First you need to change the directory, where your desired file is located

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

os.getcwd() #get current work directory
os.chdir("C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project") # change current working directory
os.getcwd() # now you are at your destination directory, where your csv file located

# now load csv to dataFrame
walmart_data = pd.read_csv("walmart.csv") #As we have already changed current working directory where our file is located, so we can directly load file
print(emp)
```

Way-02: If we don't want to change the current working directory then follow as below (must use double \)

```
walmart_data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\project\\walmart.csv")
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, and so I moved the csv file to the same folder as my other python files (working directory).

I then changed the backslashes in the file location URL to forward slashes, and the file was able to be read.